# Zustand and Typescript - persist function cannot be implemented

Tags: typescript, zustand

I would like to use the persist function in the middleware '[Zustand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zustand)' to retain the values after a refresh of the page. When I try the following code, Typescript gives me the error below. I do not know what I'm doing wrong

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persist } from "zustand/middleware";

type CoverImage = {
 isOpen: boolean;
 onOpen: () => void;
 onClose: () => void;
};

export const useCoverImage = create(
 persist<CoverImage>(
  (set) => ({
   isOpen: false,
   onClose() {
    set({ isOpen: false });
   },
   onOpen() {
    set({ isOpen: true });
   },
 }),
 { name: "coverImage" }
 )
);
```

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(initializer: StateCreator<CoverImage, [], [never, unknown][]>): UseBoundStore<StoreApi>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'StateCreator<CoverImage, [], [["zustand/persist", CoverImage]]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateCreator<CoverImage, [], [never, unknown][]>'.
> Type 'StateCreator<CoverImage, [], [["zustand/persist", CoverImage]]>' is not assignable to type '{ $$storeMutators?: [never, unknown][] | undefined; }'.
> Types of property '$$storeMutators' are incompatible.
> Type '[["zustand/persist", CoverImage]] | undefined' is not assignable to type '[never, unknown][] | undefined'.

Comment: If you are using zustand@4.4.5 then there's some issue with typing. You can use v4.4.4. Second there's no issue in your code but recommanded way to type store is to use curried version like this: `const useCoverImage = create<CoverImage>()(persist(...))`.

Comment: 4.4.4 worked after reducing version from 4.4.5